# react Semantic-UI - multi-select checkbox drop-down

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

i want to built an multi select checkbox dropdown in react with es6
my requirement is as below specified in image

[image]

I tried doing this [click here](http://instructure-react.github.io/react-select-box/) but it is not working.

Comment: I tried semantic UI, but I have not found any dropdown like this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use one parent component that will keep values in its state and toggle list items. Then you can create component for each list item that will keep active property in state that you can toggle on click.

```js
class ListItem extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {active: false}
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <a
      onClick={() => {
        this.setState(prevState => {
          let newState = !prevState.active;
          this.props.handleClick(newState, this.props.value);
          return {active: newState}
        })
      }}
      className={!this.state.active ? '' : 'selected'}
      href="#">
      {this.props.value}</a>
    )
  }
}

class Select extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showList: false,
      value: []
    }
    
    this.handleItemClick = this.handleItemClick.bind(this)
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
      if(!this.node.contains(e.target)) {
        this.setState({showList: false})
      }
    })
  }
  
  componentWillUnmount() {
     document.removeEventListener('mousedown');
  }
  
  renderValue() {
    let {value} = this.state;
    if(!value.length) return "Select..."
    else return value.join(', ')
  }
  
  toggleList() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({showList: !prevState.showList}))
  }
  
  handleItemClick(active, val) {
    let {value} = this.state;
    
    if(active) value = [...value, val]
    else value = value.filter(e => e != val);
    
    this.setState({value})
  }
  
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div 
      ref={node => this.node = node}
      className="select">
        <button onClick={this.toggleList.bind(this)}>
          <span className="select_value">
            {this.renderValue()}
          </span>
        </button>
        
        <div
        className={"select_list " + (!this.state.showList && 'hide')}>
          <ListItem handleClick={this.handleItemClick} value="Lorem" />
          <ListItem handleClick={this.handleItemClick} value="Ipsum" />
          <ListItem handleClick={this.handleItemClick} value="Dolor" />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Select />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```css
button {
  background: white;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: left;
}
.select_list {
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.select_list a {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  display: flex;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
}

.select_list a:before {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  content: '';
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: block;
}

.select_list a.selected:before {
  background: #0493D1;
  content: '✓';
  color: white;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 15px;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for your replay but dropdown ui is not reflecting as shown in the answer

Comment: document.removeEventListener('mousedown');  this lines give me error whenever i switch from one component to another. "Failed to execute 'removeEventListener' on 'EventTarget': 2 arguments required, but only 1 present."

Comment: I passed a empty function as a 2nd parameter and the issue is resolved but now whenever i switch component it gives me error on componentDidMount() function "TypeError: Cannot read property 'contains' of null". please help me @NenadVarcar

Comment: The problem is probably coming from event listener on document that i used on `componentDidMount` and that is for option to close modal when you click outside of it. But I can't tell you exactly why is that happening without your code example. Event listener should be removed on `componentWillUnmount`, so you can ether remove that functionality or try to implement it in some other way if you can't fix it like it is now.

Comment: i fixed it with "window.document.addEventListener()", but now the issue is in IE, checkbox is not visible before selection, after selection it is showing the checkbox, i think IE is not rendering it properly  because "select_list a:before" in this class Content is defined as empty so beacuse of that it is not working, please help me.... you can check this in IE.. just open this link in IE

Comment: Set display block on pseudo element.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Comment: @NenadVarcar Hi if i want to pre-select some of the values from drop-down like Lorem and Ipsum so how can i pre select  those value on 1st go.. please help me

Answer (score 1):

***Semantic-UI React Approach***

After much digging, I found an old conversation between eugenetumachov and Semantic-UI developers(?). One of the users provided incredibly helpful code that answers this question using Semantic-UI's Dropdown component.

This is done by making use of Dropdown's Dropdown.Menu and Dropdown.Item. Then looping through your options via map to create checkboxes. The only downside is that the workaround **does not seem to allow scrolling** and will require more CSS. Additionally, based on CSS the checkbox items' background color may turn transparent if you double-click on the dropdown, and the dropdown will collapse on mouse hover. You can bypass the transparency issue by using a class or style property for your Dropdown.Menu and Dropdown.Item.

Semantic-UI developer's response to this type of question appears to be a flat "no" or a

> Active items are automatically removed from the Dropdown menu. So you cannot show a "checked" state for an item in the menu.
>
> You could create a similar component out of an Input as a trigger for
> a Popup containing a Menu or List of Checkboxes.

1. [Are dropdowns with checkboxes possible? #2417](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/issues/2417#issuecomment-641941136)
2. [eugenetumachov's workaround](https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-dropdown-checkboxes-kxvq0?file=/src/App.js)